# React Router - are nested <Switch> components an anti-pattern?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

From React Router's [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node):

> All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements. Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered.

Nonetheless, nested `<Switch>` statements are allowed. I use the pattern to break up large numbers of `<Routes>`:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/foo" component={FooRouter} />
  <Route path="/bar" component={BarRouter} />
  <Route path="/baz" component={BazRouter} />
</Switch>

...

const FooRouter = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/foo/:id" component={ViewFoo} />
    <Route exact path="/foo/new" component={NewFoo} />
  </Switch>
)

const BarRouter = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/bar/new" component={NewBar} />
  </Switch>
)

....
```

Curious if there is a better method for breaking up large numbers of routes and if nested `<Switch>` statements should be avoided?

Comment: The quote you started your question with resolved my issue. After joy of React useful suggestions and warnings it's a pain to have something broken when using other libraries just because you don't remember the docs by heart.

Answer (score 3):

as you solve it just fine when you have a lot of nested route yo can speared them across the app and make a dynamic routes
but soon react-router-dom v6 will be release with a huge upgrade one of them is useRoutes
that let you configure your routes like this:

```
let element = useRoutes([
    // A route object has the same properties as a <Route>
    // element. The `children` is just an array of child routes.
    { path: '/', element: <Home /> },
    {
      path: 'users',
      element: <Users />,
      children: [
        { path: '/', element: <UsersIndex /> },
        { path: ':id', element: <UserProfile /> },
        { path: 'me', element: <OwnUserProfile /> },
      ]
    }
  ]);
```

[introduction to react-router-dom v6](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#introducing-routes) they have some cool new feature that worth to watch for
one of them is the replace of  with  witch help you a lot with nested routes and fun thing you **don't gonna need to use the exact anymore**

```
     <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<UsersIndex />} />
        <Route path=":id" element={<UserProfile />} />
        <Route path="me" element={<OwnUserProfile />} />
      </Routes>
```

this is how it gonna look with the new feature

Answer (score 2):

A note on nested conditional routes: Switch must only have Route children. If you declare Switch inside Switch, every route after Switch won't be used, i.e.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/1" />
  <Switch> ... </Switch>
  <Route path="/2" /> // this one won't work!
</Switch>
```

So don't do this, stick to declaring one route per condition or render routes as an array under common condition:

```
<Switch>
  {condition && <Route path="/1" >}
  {condition && <Route path="/2">}
  {/* or */}
  {anotherCondition && [
    // notice `key`. React will warn you about rendering a list without key prop
    <Route key="3" path="/3">,
    <Route key="4" path="/4">,
  ]}
</Switch>
```

This is true for react-router-dom v5, not sure about 6.